# MongoCollection<T> to Collection<T>

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a class called Employee. From my controller i am passing `IEnumerable<Employee>` to view. How to convert `MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollection<Employee>` to `IEnumerable<Employee>`?

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var server = MongoServer.Create("mongodb://127.0.0.1");
    var db = server.GetDatabase("employee");
    var employeeCollection = new Collection<Employee>
    {
        new Employee
        {
            EmployeeId = new ObjectId(),
            EmployeeName = "A"
        },
        new Employee
        {
            EmployeeId = new ObjectId(),
            EmployeeName = "B"
        }
    };
    var collection = db.GetCollection<Employee>("employee");

    collection.InsertBatch(employeeCollection);

    return View(collection);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use `FindAll` and that will allow you to enumerate over the entire collection:

```
return View(collection.FindAll());
```

You could also use `AsQueryable` to achieve the same result:

```
return View(collection.AsQueryable());
```

But you should be careful about doing that. The collection could possibly contain millions of documents.